# Can the formula of point charge be applied to large conductor or large charge?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, coulombs-law

[image]

The conductive sphere(green one) and the conductive spherical shell(blue one) are concentric.

Each conductor has been grounded.

We assume that the green conductor has been given the charge $Q$

$$  V'=\text{potential at point P}  $$

$$  r=\text{distance between the origin and the point P}  $$

$$  r_{1} < r < r_{2} $$

Then the following 3 equations are held.

$$  V_{1}-V_{2}= k_{e} Q \left( \frac{1}{r_{1}}-\frac{1}{r_{2}}   \right)   $$

$$  V_{1}-V'= k_{e} Q \left( \frac{1}{r_{1}}-\frac{1}{r_{}}   \right)   $$

$$  V_{2}-V'= k_{e} Q \left( \frac{1}{r_{2}}-\frac{1}{r_{}}   \right)   $$

I've come out the following thoughts.

$$  V_{1}=k_{e} Q \frac{1}{r_{1}}     $$

As I saw this, I came out the following general formula.

$$  V=\frac{k_{e} q}{r}  $$

$$  V:=\text{potential which is made by the point charge } q  $$

$$  q:=\text{point charge}  $$

$$  r:=\text{distance between the point charge and somewhere point.}  $$

I tried to apply the above against

$$  V_{1}=k_{e} Q \frac{1}{r_{1}}     $$

but the green sphere is not a point charge but the description applied this general formula.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the thing is that for a spherical distribution of charges the potential and hence the electric field intensity at any point on the surface or out of the body can be calculated by assuming the charge on the spherical body to be concentrated at the centre of the sphere.This can be proved by Gauss's Law as I have illustrated below:

The net flux through the Gaussian Surface can be written as:$$\phi=\int \vec E.d\vec A$$

Also from Gauss's law we can say :$$\phi = \frac{Q_{inside}}{\epsilon_o}$$

So we can say:$$\int \vec E.d\vec A = \frac {Q_{inside}}{\epsilon_o}$$

Since at each point on the Gaussian surface the electric field in constant due to symmetric charge distribution on the sphere , we can say:$$\vec E \int d\vec A = \frac{Q_{inside}}{\epsilon_o}$$

Since $\vec E$ and $\vec A$ are in the same direction as shown in the diagram (both are directed along the outward normal to the Gaussian surface) their dot product is simply the product of their magnitudes.So,$$ E . 4\pi r^2 = \frac{Q_{inside}}{\epsilon_o}$$

Therefore,
$$ E = \frac{Q_{inside}}{4 \pi  \epsilon_o r^2}$$

which is the formula we use for the field intensity of a point charge .Now to find potential ,

$$\vec E = - \frac{dV}{d \vec r}$$
or , $$ dV = - \vec E.d\vec r$$
$$\int^{V_p}_0  dv = -\int^{r}_{\infty} \vec E.d\vec r$$$$V_p=-\Biggl[-\frac{Q_{inside}}{4 \pi  \epsilon_o r}\Biggl]^r_{\infty}$$
$$V_p = \frac{Q_{inside}}{4 \pi  \epsilon_o r}$$

which is the formula we use for potential of a point charge.Thus we can conclusively say that the formula we use for potential and field of a point charge can be used for spheres by considering the charge to be concentrated at the centre.

**EDIT:Here $Q_{inside}$ is the net charge inside the Gaussian surface which is equal to the net charge on the sphere in this case.**

[image]